# Periodicity of powers (and recurrences) $\!\bmod n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, periodic-functions

My numeric tests showed that the sequence of the remainders of $n^k$ divided by $m$ are periodic with respect to $k$ $(n, k, m \in \mathbb{Z}^+, n < m)$.

For example, for $n = 7$ and $m = 30$:

$k = 1: \quad 7^1 = 7 = 0 \cdot 30 + \fbox{7}$
$k = 2: \quad 7^2 = 49 = 1 \cdot 30 + \fbox{19}$
$k = 3: \quad 7^3 = 343 = 11 \cdot 30 + \fbox{13}$
$k = 4: \quad 7^4 = 2401 = 80 \cdot 30 + \fbox{1}$
$k = 5: \quad 7^5 = 16807 = 560 \cdot 30 + 7$
$k = 6: \quad 7^6 = 117649 = 3921 \cdot 30 + 19$
$k = 7: \quad 7^7 = 823543 = 27451 \cdot 30 + 13$
$k = 8: \quad 7^8 = 5764801 = 192160 \cdot 30 + 1$
$k = 9: \quad 7^9 = 40353607 = 1345120 \cdot 30 + 7$
$\vdots$

In this case, the remainders apparently have a **period of 4**: $7, 19, 13, 1$.

My questions:
a) Does such a period always exist?
b) Is there a way to **calculate the length of the period from $n$ and $m$**, without calculating the remainders as I did above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Yes, this sequence is always periodic, though it may start with a pre-periodic sequence.

The reason is that the remainder of $n^k$ divided by $m$ completely determines the remainder of $n^{k+1}$ divided by $m$, even if you don't know the value of $k$.

This is a special case of the fact that if you know the remainder of a number $a$ when divided by $m$, and the remainder of $b$ when divided by $m$, you know the remainder of $ab$ when divided by $m$, even if you don't know $a$ and $b$ specifically. That's the basis of  [calculation modulo m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Since the number of possible remainders is finite ($=m$), a remainder has to repeat in the sequence $n^k$, and once the remainder of $n^{k_1}$ and $n^{k_2}$ is the same, so must be (by what I said above) $n^{k_1+1}$ and $n^{k_2+1}$, a.s.o. so the sequence of remainders repeated indefinitely.

To see an example with a pre-period sequence, consider $n=6, m=20$, where the remainder sequence is $6,16,16,\ldots$ This can only happen when $n$ and $m$ have a common divisor $>1$.

b) You can get some information on the period length, but if $m$ is really big, it might still not be easy to test all possibilities.

First, you can ignore all common prime factors of $n$ and $m$. If $p$ is such a factor, and $p^a$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $m$, then $n^k$ will for all $k\ge a$ always be divisible by $p^a$. So the only remainders that will occur are those that are divisible by $p^a$ for $k\ge a$. So considering what happens for the prime factor $p$ is no longer giving any restriction, so it can be ignored.

So you can reduce $n$ and $m$ to $n'$ and $m'$ by dividing out their common prime factors (this can be done algorithimally fast by using the Euclidean algorithm). Then it is known that the length of the period must be a divisor of $\phi(m')$, where $\phi$ represents [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Calculating $\phi$ when $m'$ is big and has an unknown prime number decomposition is hard. Even if you can do it, $\phi(m')$ might have a lot of divisiors, and **as far as I know** there is no easy way to find out which divisor is the period length. But I'm not an expert on this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** this follows from the periodicity of recurrences on finite rings. The power sequence $f_k = a^k\,$ satisfies the  recurrence $\,f_{k+1} = a f_k,\ f_0 = 1.\,$ Since it take values in a *finite* ring $\, R = \Bbb Z_{30}\,$ the Pigeonhole Principle implies it eventually repeats: say $\,\color{#c00}{f_{j+n} = f_j}\,$ so induction using the recurrence shows it continues to repeat in-step for larger indices, i.e.

$$\begin{align} \color{#0a0}{f_{1+j+n}} &= a \color{#c00}{f_{0+j+n}} = a \color{#c00}{f_{0+j}} = \color{#0a0}{f_{1+j}},\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ \ \,a \ \left[ f_{n+j} = f_n\right]\rightarrow f_{1+j+n} = f_{1+j}\\
 f_{2+j+n} &= a \color{#0a0}{f_{1+j+n}} = a  \color{#0a0}{f_{1+j}} = f_{2+j},\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ \  a^2 \left[ f_{n+j} = f_n\right]\rightarrow f_{2+j+n} = f_{2+j}\\
&\ \ \,\vdots\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \  \vdots\\
  &\phantom{a \color{#0a0}{f_{k-1+j+n}} = a  \color{#0a0}{f_{1+j}} = 
f_{2+j},\ \ \ \ \ }{\rm i.e.}\ \ \  a^k \left[ f_{n+j} = f_n\right]\rightarrow f_{k+j+n} = f_{k+j}
\end{align}\qquad$$

Hence, $\, f_K = f_k\,$ if $K\equiv k\pmod{\! n}$  and $\,K,k\ge j,\,$ i.e.   once both indices are $\ge j\, $ we enter a cycle of length $\,n,\,$ i.e.   $\rm\color{#0af}{MOR}$ = [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) eventually applies. This holds even if $\,j\,$ and $\,n\,$ are not the minimal possible values. When we choose them minimal - so $n$ is the *order* of the cycle - then we get a converse - just like in $\rm\color{#0af}{MOR}$.

**Remark:** $\! $ **oh vs. rho orbits: $\!$ permutation orbits are cycles, i.e. o-shaped vs. $\rho$-shaped**
When $\,a\,$ is coprime to the modulus $\,n\,$ then the shift map $f_n \to f_{n+1} = a f_n\,$ is invertible, so being an invertible map on a finite set it is a permutation, whose orbits are *purely periodic*, i.e. **cycles**, i.e. o-shaped (vs. generally having a *preperiodic* part, i.e. $\rho$-shaped, i.e. $\,j> 0).\,$  This simple general fact about such periodicity is often overlooked, resulting in  [reinventing the wheel (cycle)](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20wheel%20cycle).

**Generally** the same argument works over any *finite* commutative ring $R$ when we have a (nonlinear) recurrence of order $k$ of form $\,f_{n+k} = g(f_{n+k-1},\ldots,f_0)$ for $\,g\,$ a polynomial over $R$, i.e. where the next value is a polynomial function of the prior $k$ values. As above it is eventually periodic  by $R$ is finite so there are only finitely many sequences of $k$ values from $R$ so they must eventually repeat as a subsequence in the sequence $\,f_n,\,$ hence the values of $f_i$ repeat in-step after these matching points, by induction - as above. If the recurrence is linear then we can represent the shift map as a matrix $A$ and then the repetition occurs via scaling by powers of $A$. In particular $\,f_n\,$ can be computed *efficiently* by repeated squaring of $A$, e.g. as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1888494/242) for fast computation of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2003925/242) for many examples of $\,a^{j+n}\equiv a^j\pmod{n}\ \ $